# Can't view image in Email sent PHP, JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a child window with table. When I click a row (with button select), the text is successfully transfered to the opener or parent window. I want to send image inline with my text using php's/sendmail's **function: mail()**. Sending email with text only is successful.
The email sent is in html format so I can change contents' appearance (bold letters, italic etc.)
But when I send email with image, I cant see it in my email. How to fix it? Or how to send email with inline image? I have my code here:

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#products-table .selectbtn').click(function() {

    var td = $(this).closest('tr');

    var f;
    var s;
    var t;
    var q;
    var w;

    $(td).each(function(){
        f = $(this).find(".class").html(); 
        s = $(this).find(".brand").html(); 
        t = $(this).find(".model").html(); 
        q = $(this).find(".price").html(); 
        w = $(this).find(".terms").html(); 
        g = $(this).find(".img").html(); 
    });

    var x = 'Class: ' + f + '\n' + 'Brand: ' + s + '\n' + 'Model: ' + t + '\n' + 'Price: ' + q + '\n' + 'Terms: ' + w;
    var z = g + '<br/>' + '<b>Class:</b> ' + f + '<br/>\n' + '<b>Brand: </b>' + s + '<br/>\n' + '<b>Model: </b>' + t + '<br/>\n' + '<b>Price: </b>' + q + '<br/>\n' + '<b>Terms: </b>' + w;
    opener.document.motorappform.productdesc.value = x;
    opener.document.motorappform.productdeschidden.value = z;
    self.close();
});
});
```

The **z** variable will be the one to be send to my email as my message for the parameters of **mail()** (that is already in html format so I dont have problem about that). The value of the **g** will be like:

```
<img src = "folder/image.png"></img>
```

These are my php code:

```
<?php

$fullname = $_POST["fname"].' '.$_POST["mname"].' '.$_POST["lname"];
$contact = $_POST["contact"];
$category = $_POST["finance-type"];
$location = $_POST["city"].', '.$_POST["province"];
$senderemail = $_POST["email"];
$birthday = $_POST["month"].' '.$_POST["dd"].', '.$_POST["yyyy"];
$productdesc =$_POST["productdeschidden"];
$subject = "Loan Application";
$email;
$message;

if($category == "Motorcycle Financing")
{
$email = "email@email.com";
$message = "<html><head></head><body><b>Service Type:</b> ".$category."<br/> <br/>"."<b>Name:</b>         ".$fullname."<br/>"."<b>Birthdate:</b> ".$birthday."<br/>"."<b>Location: </b>".$location."<br/>"."    <b>Contact No: </b>".$contact."<br/>"."<b>Email:</b> ".$senderemail."<br/> <br/>"."<b>Requested        motorcycle to loan</b><br/>".$productdesc."<br/> <br/>"."<b>Message:</b> <br/>".$_POST["message"]."    </body></html>";

}

else if ($category == "RX Cash Line")
{
$email = "email@email.com";
$message = "<html><head></head><body><b>Service Type:</b> ".$category."<br/> <br/>"."<b>Name:</b>     ".$fullname."<br/>"."<b>Birthdate:</b> ".$birthday."<br/>"."<b>Location: </b>".$location."<br/>"."    <b>Contact No: </b>".$contact."<br/>"."<b>Email:</b> ".$senderemail."<br/> <br/>"."<b>Message:</b>     <br/>".$_POST["message"]."</body></html>";

}

else if ($category == "MFC Factors")
{
$email = "email@email.com";
$message = "<html><head></head><body><b>Service Type:</b> ".$category."<br/> <br/>"."<b>Name:</b> ".$fullname."<br/>"."<b>Birthdate:</b> ".$birthday."<br/>"."<b>Location: </b>".$location."<br/>"."<b>Contact No: </b>".$contact."<br/>"."<b>Email:</b> ".$senderemail."<br/> <br/>"."<b>Message:</b> <br/>".$_POST["message"]."</body></html>";

}


$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: MFC Website". "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: email@email.com' . "\r\n";


if (mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
    echo '
            <script>
                alert ("Message Sent!");
                window.location.href = "index.html";
            </script>
        ';
}
else
{
    echo '
            <script>
                alert ("Failed to send message");
                window.location.href = "index.html";
            </script>
        ';
}
?>
```

Everything is fine except for the image sent. I don't see the exact image and I only see an icon with crack on my email. How can I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: `<img src = "http://www.example.com/folder/image.png">` - It need a full web URL. Plus, you can take out the `</img>`.

Comment: it still doesn't work my friend

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code where `$message` is? Even, the way you're including it in the message.

Comment: Edited it. The value of **g** is stored in **$productdesc**

Comment: Ok, but how is it defined?

Comment: You need to do `$productdesc = '<img src = "http://www.yourSite.com/folder/image.png">';` try that just before `$message...`

Comment: How can I change the source for the image? It from a child page with a table, a tr, a td. When I click a button, all text from the row where the image belong will be transferred to a textarea of a parent window. So the text for the image will be like `<img src = 'folder/pic.png'>`

Comment: Where you have `$productdesc` right now, try replacing it with `<img src=\"http://www.yourSite.com/folder/$productdesc\">` you may need to play with the quotes a bit.

Comment: Actually, I posted an answer below, you can see what I mean better.

Comment: ahh.! now it works. you're right friend.

Comment: Great. You can accept my answer below to close 'er up ;-)

Comment: Um.... You accepted the wrong answer. You didn't choose mine; why? Did you not see it?

Comment: I do all the work and you accept the other answer? What's up with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When wanting to show images in an Email, it needs a full Web address complete with `http://`

Here is one example from a line I took from your code:

```
$message = "<html><head></head><body><b>Service Type:</b> ".$category."<br/> <br/>"."<b>Name:</b> ".$fullname."<br/>"."<b>Birthdate:</b> ".$birthday."<br/>"."<b>Location: </b>".$location."<br/>"."    <b>Contact No: </b>".$contact."<br/>"."<b>Email:</b> ".$senderemail."<br/> <br/>"."<b>Requested        motorcycle to loan</b><br/>" . "<img src=\"http://www.yourSite.com/folder/$productdesc\">" . "<br/> <br/>"."<b>Message:</b> <br/>".$_POST["message"]."    </body></html>";
```

Notice the:

```
. "<img src=\"http://www.yourSite.com/folder/$productdesc\">" .
```

This assuming that your POST will render as something like:

```
$productdesc = "image.png";
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be use full path of website, include `http://mydomain[dot]com/folder/image.png`